# How to add function for rightButtons and leftButtons in this case?

Tags: react-native

I am a beginner in React Native. I am make a small project, but I don't understand some things. How to add function for rightButtons and leftButtons in this case?

This is my code:

```
Community.options = {
  topBar: {
    animate: true,
    elevation: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Sharing Community',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      alignment: 'center',
    },
    leftButtons: [
      {
        id: 'backButton',
        icon: require('../../assets/icons/back-button.png'),
        color: '#5B7C56',
      },
    ],
    rightButtons: [
      {
        id: 'rightButton',
        icon: require('../../assets/icons/add.png'),
        color: '#5B7C56',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Can you provide some context as to how `Community.options` is used?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to go to another screens. Is this work with Community.options. Thank you @Moistbobo!

Comment: Can you give an example how these options are used?

Comment: As youy can see in this screen: [link](https://i.ibb.co/9Zv7rk0/S10323-082017.jpg])_italic_ **bold**. So I want to use add and back button on the top bar to come to anthor screen. But I don't know how and no material for this. Could you help me @Moistbobo, please?

Comment: Are you using React Navigation? Try taking a look at the `headerLeft` and `headerRight` properties here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerright